# Count the number of occurrences of a specific word from a text file, C++

Tags: c++

The code is meant to count the number of times of the specific word you type from a text file. 
        My code so far:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string word;
        string wif;
        fstream file("words.txt");
        int nTimes = 0;
        cin >> word;
        while (file >> wif) {
            cout << wif << " ";
            if (wif == word) {
                ++nTimes;
            }
        }
        cout << nTimes << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The code works but not what i expect.
For an example: the file has a total of 6 "many" words, but the output is 4, some of the words are like this: Many, MANY? 
Is it not adding those words because of the characters , and ?

Comment: So? Just remove those characters from the string, and convert everything else to lowercase, before comparing the strings. What exactly is the problem, here?

Comment: The point is to count how many times the word appears even if there are characters and upercase